# How do I move only images taken by my camera to an album?

Tags: iphone, photos, camera

I have a lot of pictures taken by my camera, but I also have a lot of images taken by me as a screenshot or saved from some online source.

I'd like to ONLY have pictures taken directly by me via the camera or a camera app into an album.

Is there anyway to do this with Shortcuts or IFTTT?